# Need to specify numericals in sed command

Tags: linux, text-processing, sed

I have a fasta file as shown below,

```
>accessory/4745/24/lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_chromosome_Gene2509
ATGCTAG
>accessory/95/89.78/lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_Gene125
TAGTCT
```

I need to remove characters of `accessory/numericals/numericals/` from the fasta header, so I used the following command but it failed to serve my purpose.

```
sed 's/accessory[/][0-9][/][0-9]//g' accessory.fasta
```

The expected output is

```
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_chromosome_Gene2509
ATGCTAG
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_Gene125
TAGTCT
```

Please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your regular expression is looking for "`accessory/` and then *one number* (`[0-9]`) and then a `/`", which doesn't occur in your file. You want to search for *one or more numbers*, and you also want to allow `.` which isn't a number. So, using the same logic as your original, you would want something like this:

```
$ sed -E 's/accessory[/][0-9.]+[/][0-9.]+[/]//' accessory.fasta
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_chromosome_Gene2509
ATGCTAG
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_Gene125
TAGTCT
```

Note how I didn't use the `g` modifier since that is useless here because there will only be one match per line.

However, that is needlessly restrictive. If the file is as you show, you just want to remove everything until the last `/` on the line:

```
$ sed -E 's|>.*/|>|' accessory.fasta 
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_chromosome_Gene2509
ATGCTAG
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_Gene125
TAGTCT
```

The `s///` operator can take any character as a delimiter. So since I know I will need to match `/`, I used `s|||` to avoid needing to escape the `/`.

If you really need to be as restrictive as your original, you could simplify to:

```
$ sed -E 's|accessory/[0-9.]+/[0-9.]+/||' accessory.fasta 
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_chromosome_Gene2509
ATGCTAG
>lake_sample_pv_strain_LH201_Gene125
TAGTCT
```